# Doctrine2 chained multi-table join and filtering

Tags: mysql, sql, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to solve an issue with selecting only valid results with a chained join in doctrine, but can't find a decent solution. To simplify it as much as possible:

- **DB Schema**: Posts can have multiple Comments, each comment is written by Author.
- **Task**: Get list of Posts, with each having 0 to N active comments written by only active Authors.

Basic query that I'm trying to use as a start is:

```
$queryBuilder
    ->select('p', 'c', 'a')
    ->from('AppBundle:Post', 'p')
    ->leftJoin('p.comment', 'c', Join::WITH, 'o.isActive = 1')
    ->leftJoin('c.author', 'a', Join::WITH, 'a.isActive = 1')
;
```

however obviously that one still yields all comments without taking into account 'a.isActive'.

The only other way I can see is creating subquery for "All active comments by active authors" and then joining it to Comment table in the main query, however it seems that Doctrine does not allow that

```
...
->leftJoin($subquery, 'GoodComments', Join::ON, 'GoodComments.comment_id = c.id')
...
```

So am I missing something or is native SQL the only way to go? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

As I can't write comments, I'll provide it here.

Did you try to use simple where conditions as an alternative?

```
->leftJoin('p.comment', 'c')
->leftJoin('c.author', 'a')
->andWhere('o.isActive=1')
->andWhere('a.isActive=1')
```